# Flag multiple rows of a record if one row is missing data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have been struggling to find a solution to the problem best explained by the image below.

What I am trying to do is flag a series of cells (which make up a single record over a number of rows) if one of the record’s rows contains a blank.

[image: example table]

As you can see from the image, cell C7 is missing the year so all records of BBB will need to be flagged as they will be potentially invalid in my data. The records will likely be manually cleaned or removed at a later stage.

I am easily able to create a flag for the one row where the year is missing (with ISBLANK) but I need a the other flag cells of the same ID to be filled as well.

If anyone has any thoughts as to a solution to this I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work in 2007 / 2010:

*If it returns an error or incorrect result, try confirming it as an array formula by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.*

```
=IF(MOD(SUMPRODUCT(N(LEN(IF($A$2:$A$10=A2,IF($A$2:$D$10="","",$A$2:$D$10),""))>0)),4)=0,"",1)
```

**algorithm**

- Return an array of just the rows the match with ID
- Do some manipulations to return `""` instead of `0` for the unmatched rows
- Count the number of resultant strings with length > 0
- Check that the number of strings with length > 0 is a factor of 4.

  - If not, output a flag.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, this works great for getting the numbered flag in the last column. Thank you very much! As with the other answer I gave an upvote but I don't have enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula to format cells if year is blank:

```
=$A2=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK($C$2:$C$10),0))
```

or if you need check any field:

```
=OR(IFERROR($A2=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK($B$2:$B$10),0)),0),IFERROR($A2=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK($C$2:$C$10),0)),0),IFERROR($A2=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK($D$2:$D$10),0)),0))
```

[image]

**Edit**

To use formulas in a cell, enter them as an array formulas. Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution. I’m getting an error box when trying to use the formulas: https://i.imgur.com/Uju4uE0.png I’ve tried fixing it myself to no avail and am not sure what I’ve done wrong.

Is there a way I can adapt this to fill Column E with a numbered flag for all IDs with missing years? E.g ‘1’s in my example image - my coloring was meant more to highlight the example. I tried adjusting your formulas with no success, Excel is not my strong point.

Comment: Thanks. I found out I was getting the error because I had an exotic delimiter set up in the Windows regional settings which was messing with the formula. It's working fine now. Thanks again, I just gave an upvote but I don't have enough rep for it to be counted.